# Create a list of repeated consecutive numbers regarding number from another list

Tags: python

I want to create a list with repeated consecutive numbers from zero regarding numbers from `list1`

```
list1 = [3,5,4,1,2,2]
```

Expected list should have 3 zeros, 5 ones, 4 twos, and so on.

```
list2 = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5]
```

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a nested *list comprehension* using `range` to make the repetitions:

```
lst = [i for i in range(len(list1)) for _ in range(list1[i])]
print lst
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

And there's the more intuitive `itertools` approach:

```
from itertools import repeat, count

c = count()
lst = [x for i in list1 for x in repeat(next(c), i)]
```

Comment: After reading your answer, I finally figure out what the question is :) +1

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a list comprehension, but it's a little more efficient to use a traditional `for` loop and the `.extend` method.

```
list1 = [3,5,4,1,2,2]
list2 = []
for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    list2.extend([i] * v)
print(list2)
```

**output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

---

Another option is to use `itertools.chain`:

```
list2 = list(chain.from_iterable([i] * v for i, v in enumerate(list1)))
```

or, the slightly shorter, but more cryptic

```
list2 = list(chain(*([i] * v for i, v in enumerate(list1))))
```

Comment: FWIW, I _didn't_ copy that last one from eugene, I wrote it independently.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over count/value pairs:

```
>>> list1 = [3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2]
>>> [j for i, n in enumerate(list1) for j in [i]*n]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (or [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)), especially if you don't always need to build a list in memory:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*[[i]*n for i, n in enumerate(list1)]))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Comment: I think your list comp is more efficient than Moses` since it avoids the inner `range` calls.

Comment: @ PM 2Ring: Yep, on my machine it's faster: `%timeit [i for i in range(len(list1)) for _ in range(list1[i])] {...} 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.73 µs per loop   %timeit [j for i, n in enumerate(list1) for j in [i]*n] {...} 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 µs per loop`